# Create Index on 2 columns, combo has to be unique

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns in a table (action, id) action is an enum and can be the values 'ready', 'set' or 'go'. ID is an int value, but I want the ID to have a unique action. For an example:

ID with the value of 1 can have an action of 'ready', 'set' or 'go', but ID with the value of 1 can't have the action 'ready' twice (I hope that makes sense), but ID with the value of 1 can have another row with the action 'ready' and 'set' or 'go'

| ID | action |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ready |
| 1 | set |
| 1 | go |
| 2 | ready |
| 2 | set |
| 2 | go |

This is for an existing table with these values already existing. When I try to create an index like so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_action ON myTable (id, action);
```

I get this error:

> Duplicate entry 'ready' for key 'id_action'

Is there away to do this with already existing data?

Would exporting my data, removing the table, re-creating the table, then creating the indexes then importing the data work?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ocKURy9qg9hDBkxYgPNbHt/0

Comment: That's not a possible error message for a 2-column index. When it shows the duplicate entry, it would show it as `column1-column2`, e.g. `duplicate entry '1-ready'`. I suspect you actually wrote `ON myTable(action)`

Answer (score 0):

Your data (not the data you have shown us here) does not conform to your predicate. You can easily identify the cases with:

```
SELECT id, action, COUNT(*) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, action
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

We don't know how you should resolve it since you've told us such cases should not exist.